Google Drive API File Upload is not showing erros yet not uploading to connected drive
I am attemting to connect my google drive to my application so I can upload files to it.
I have followed the documentation and already set up my application on the google cloud portal, created my OAuth client ID and my Service Account to be able to connect it to my application. When testing using postman and my client ID, I am able to upload files to my drive but the file name is not being sent with my file. After attemting to solve the issue for a while I decided to move on to implementing it in the application instead to see that there is not even a file being uploaded in my google drive.
The following is the method that will upload the files:
        public async Task DriveUploadBasic(string filePath) {
            try {
                // Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
                string keyPath = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\googleapi1.json";
                GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(keyPath)
                    .CreateScoped(DriveService.Scope.Drive)
                    .CreateScoped(DriveService.Scope.DriveFile);

                // Create Drive API service.
                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "TestingApp1"
                });

                //service.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);

                // Upload file photo.jpg on drive.
                var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File() {
                    Name = "test1.csv"
                };
                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
                // Create a new file on drive.
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)) {
                    // Create a new file, with metadata and stream.
                    request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "text/csv");
                    request.Fields = "id";
                    var progress = await request.UploadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    if (progress.Status == UploadStatus.Failed) {
                        Log($"Upload failed: {progress.Exception}");
                    }

                    var file = request.ResponseBody;
                    //Log(request.ResponseBody.ToString());
                    // Prints the uploaded file id.
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                if (e is AggregateException) {
                    Log("Credential Not found");
                }
                else if (e is FileNotFoundException) {
                    Log("File not found");
                }
                else {
                    Log(e.Message);                    
                }
            }
        }

Any help is amazing thank you!
When debuggin this, here are my findings:

The connection is created with the service, no exception is thrown
The upload file is being read (all 882 bytes)
My request tells me that the process is completed and that all 882 bytes were sent
The response body provides me with a new id, which is supposed to be the id of the file in my drive.
- Although it all looks good there is no file in my drive.

Possible issue:

my stream is giving a read and write timeout error but I do not bleive that it had to do with anything since my file is being read and all bytes are claimed to be sent. This error might be due to inconsistent internet connection.

Any help is amazing thank you!
